# Call removing method for all set members

Tags: java, iterator, set, hashset, element

In a program, I have a `HashSet` of `Foo`:

```
final Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<>();
// add a lot of elements to the set

class Foo {
  public void destroy() {
    // other stuff [such as removing this as event handler]
    set.remove(this);
  }
}
```

**I want to call `destroy()` for all members of the set.**

The purpose of the `destroy()` method is to remove the element as handler for events and from the set.

This is what I have tried:

- Use an Iterator / for each loop - throws `ConcurrentModificationException`:

  `for (Iterator<Foo> i = set.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) { i.next().destroy() }`
- Remove one element at the time - horrible inefficient:

  `while (!set.isEmpty()) { set.iterator().next().destory(); }`

I am looking for a solution to this problem that works well with very many elements in the set. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can set.clear(); help you out?

Comment: @BrunoFranco That helps but what about `//doing other stuff` ?? –

Comment: Try implementing/overriding finalize() in your class and within finalize you can handle the //doing other stuff - read tutorials on how to PROPERLY override finalize method java java.lang.Object and you need to invoke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done in your first attempt.

Try

```
   for (Iterator<Foo> i = set.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Foo foo = i.next();  
        // other stuff with foo. Something like foo.someOtherStuff();
        i.remove();
   }
```

That will remove safely from the set. Need not to call destroy even.